# Failed to execute PostMessage on DOMWindow using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am getting the following error message occasionally when I open my web-app with apps script.

**Need to clarify two questions**

- What is this error?
- How do I fix it?

I need this website to run consistently obviously so I am willing to start a bounty in a few days if the solution is not obvious.  I make many calls to google.script.run functions.

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': 
The target origin provided 
('https://n-j3xfpwqmogabbvlhsvezfcvbljow7bq45m6qoky-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com') 
does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').
```

Edit: I should probably mention that my app contains jquery, but when I remove the script and Css tags below there is no overall effect. It just simply is not loading sometimes for no apparent reason.

```
 <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"   integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"   integrity="sha256-0YPKAwZP7Mp3ALMRVB2i8GXeEndvCq3eSl/WsAl1Ryk="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based from the error `Failed to execute postMessage on DOMWindow` you might not properly configured your credentials from [Google API console](https://cloud.google.com/console/) or you are trying to run your script from the file system instead of web server even running on `localhost`

Just make sure that posting message is loaded. Most of the time this error occurred when sending messages failed to load.

Try to check workaround suggested by community here: [SOTicket1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573017/failed-to-execute-postmessage-on-domwindow-https-www-youtube-com-http) or [SOTicket2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882594/failed-to-execute-postmessage-on-domwindow-target-origin-mismatch-http-vs-h).

Comment: Can you elaborate no the "Credentials" part.

Comment: You may check the link above mate. Check your dashboard, where credentials are generated.